# How to add file to repo from Bitbucket Server like GitHub

Tags: bitbucket, bitbucket-server

I am on version v6.6.3 of Atlassian Bitbucket Server:

From the GitHub website, I can freely add new files and edit existing files without needing to clone / push.  In Bitbucket, I can freely edit any existing file by clicking on the file in the "Source" tab, but there does not seem to be any option to add new files.

Is there a way to add a new file to a repository in Bitbucket without needing to clone / push anything?

Is there an equivalent to the "Create new file" button from GitHub in Bitbucket?
[image]

Here is what my repo view looks like in Bitbucket Server:
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Bitbucket Cloud (v.7.1) provides the **Add file** option in every page level under the project source:

[image: Add file]

It will be added as a new commit.

[image: Comit]

Comment: I think I am on a different version than you, I am on version v6.6.3 of Atlassian Bitbucket Server.  I have edited my original post with a screenshot of what my repo view looks like.  -thank you for your time

Comment: Is it possible to add an Excel file this way?

Comment: No. The "add file" option doesn't work as a file uploader. It only provides a code editor, with syntax support to a bunch of different programming languages.